# Bash, saber em que diretoria está a ser executado

Tags: bash, diretório

Como faço para obter o caminho do diretório no qual o *script* em [*bash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) está localizado, de dentro do próprio *script*?

```
#!/bin/bash

MINHADIR="caminho/para/onde/estou" # apanhar a diretoria onde estou atualmente
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se isto responte à pergunta mas:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "A script está em: $0"
echo "O invocador está em $PWD"
```

**Update 1** imprimir o path absoluto do script

Para obter o path absoluto, começamos por juntar a diretoria actual com 
a directoria da script ( `$PWD "=" dirname $0 "/"`).

Seguidamente reescrevemos (neste caso usando perl) os casos em que q directoria
da script é um path relativo (`./d`  `../../b`  `b/c`) usando substituições.

Assim sendo:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s=%s/" $PWD `dirname $0` |         # formatar como "$PWD=$0/"
    perl -pe 'while(s!/[^/]+=\.\./!=!){};   # a/b=../c --> a=c
              s!.*=/|=\./?!=! ;             # a/b=/c --> =c ;  b=./c => b=c 
              s!=!/!; '
```

ou mesmo

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dir=$(printf .......e mais as outras 3 linhas... )    
echo $script_dir
```

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, ou seja, o `$0` está a devolver a _path_ que usei para aceder e executar o _script_, já o `$PWD` está a devolver a _path_ onde me encontro. A ideia seria, independentemente do local onde me encontro, obter a _path_ do script, exemplo: `O seu _script_ está localizado em: /home/zuul/bash/`, que é diferente da _path_ utilizada para o executar, exemplo: `O caminho utilizado para aceder ao script foi: ../../bash/`. **Nota:** Se estiver pouco claro, avisa que edito a pergunta para clarificar a ideia.

Comment: @zuul, a resposta implicita na minha resposta era: `dirname $0` (podendo este ser absoluto ou relativo). Presumo portanto que precisas do path absoluto. Certo? Há também a questão da possivel existências de links simbólicos etc. que proponho que se ignore.

Comment: Sim, absoluto e simbólicos ignorados... Imagina o caso em que pretendemos trabalhar com ficheiros na localização do _script_.

Comment: @zuul, Por favor, vê se este update faz sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez uma solução mais genérica seja:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROGNAME=$(basename $0)
PROGDIR=$(readlink -m $(dirname $0))
```

Essa também funciona para diretórios com links.